# Simplify C++ code with macro. Error: pasting "<" and "string" does not give a valid preprocessing token

Tags: c++, macros, escaping

I'm looking for a solution, how to simplify C++ code.

There is a lot of similar methods in a class and I need to check the type of data in JSON in every single method. Copy+paste of this block and just change required type (in this case "string") is a little bit clumsy. My original and working code validation block looks like this

```
if(json_data_incomming.get("value").is<string>()){
    __TRACE("argument type OK\n");
} else {
    __ERROR("invalid type\n");
    _result.rc = ERROR_CODE_INVALID_TYPE;
    _req_done(&_result);
    return;
}
```

My goal is to create some validation macro like this:

```
JSON_CHECK_TYPE(string)
```

or:

```
JSON_CHECK_TYPE(<string>)
```

I tried to define concat my macro like:

```
#define JSON_CHECK_TYPE(TYPE) if(json_data_incomming.get("value").is<##TYPE##>()){\
    __TRACE("argument type OK\n");\
} else {\
    __ERROR("invalid type\n");\
    _result.rc = ERROR_CODE_INVALID_TYPE;\
    _req_done(&_result);\
    return;\
}
```

but without success - compiler returns an error:

> error: pasting "<" and "string" does not give a valid preprocessing token

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is it really necessary to use macro? Can you replace the macro with function?

Comment: `is<##TYPE##>` -> `is<TYPE>`

Comment: When faced with a syntactical problem in C++, you may think "I know, I'll solve it with macros!"  Now you have two problems.

Comment: Identifiers that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter, or which contain double underscores are reserved for the system.

Comment: Use a template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is macro, you are looking for:

```
#define JSON_CHECK_TYPE(type)                               \
    do {                                                    \
        if(json_data_incomming.get("value").is<type>()){    \
            __TRACE("argument type OK\n");                  \
        } else {                                            \
            __ERROR("invalid type\n");                      \
            _result.rc = ERROR_CODE_INVALID_TYPE;           \
            _req_done(&_result);                            \
            return;                                         \
        }                                                   \
} while(false)
```

In this macro, part `do {` and `} while(false)` used to make possible this:

```
if(condition)
    JSON_CHECK_TYPE(string);
else
    // Do other useful things
```

Comment: So concat with ## was just unnecessary in my solution. Part with do/while is just a little bonus.  Thanks a lot.